# Client side filtering in Gridx when using jsonrest with pagination?

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I am using Gridx with jsonrest as the store and pagination module. Can the filtering be done client side only? Currently it sends request to the jsonrest store and that queries the server.

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, see this:
https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/How-to-filter-Gridx-with-any-condition,

just exclude the part about serverside mode and gridx will perform filtering on clientside, only querying server as needed to fill the rows on your page.